# InvalidArgumentException: Malformed URL: bashdress is not a valid URL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to upload images to instagram through keywords. But it tells me that my url is not valid.
Can someone help me, please?
my code:

[image]

Comment: Copy and paste code here please! link to image is not an appropriate way to show us the code.

Comment: Does the error happen on `driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  Also, please edit your question to include the code (rather than post as a screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")` to `driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")` -- the trailing slash might be causing a problem.

Comment: the problem is I can't execute all my code : InvalidArgumentException: Malformed URL: zara is not a valid URL.

Comment: Zara is the keyword for the search

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you are using Zara.